# API or Catalog operations for creating Hive External table using HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop3

I'm using HDP 3.X cluster and running spark sql using spark_llap, Is there a way to create external hive table using hive.createTable because the example provided in Hortonworks website is to use following code whereas this code will create manged table but I need external table.

```
hive.createTable("web_sales").ifNotExists().column("sold_time_sk", "bigint").column("ws_ship_date_sk", "bigint").create()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use spark session to create a table.

example1 :

```
  //drop the table if already created
    spark.sql("drop table if exists my_table");
    //create the table using the dataframe schema
    spark.sql("create table my_table(....
    ") row format delimited fields terminated by '|' location '/my/hdfs/location'");
```

[example 2:](https://datascienceplus.com/leveraging-hive-with-spark-using-python/)

```
spark.sql('create table movies \
         (movieId int,title string,genres string) \
         row format delimited fields terminated by ","\
         stored as textfile')                                              # in textfile format
spark.sql("create table ratings\
           (userId int,movieId int,rating float,timestamp string)\
           stored as ORC" )
```